# ActiveMQ Websocket transport with maximumConnections

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic

I'm trying to load test ActiveMQ using the default websocket connector:

```
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

However, despite the `maximumConnections` attribute, I managed to have more 
than 2000 consumers successfully connected. I can see the 2000+ connections 
using `netstat -an`.

Do the transport connection attributes work for this websocket transport? 
Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: What do you see if you do something like `netstat -an | grep 61614`?

Comment: Also, you might consider using [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) for high performance applications instead of ActiveMQ 5.x as overall performance in Artemis is much greater due to its non-blocking architecture.

Comment: `netstat -an | grep 61614` gives me as many lines as connection I have opened from my clients, so more than 2000 in my case.